# How to create custom letters in TKinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to create custom letters in a window in centimeters, similar to the image below:
[image]

I tried to create a canvas in the same configuration to insert the letter into it, while the canvas came in the size as expected, am not sure how to fit the letter E into the size. Here is what i have tried so far

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


my_window = Tk()

my_window.title('VA chart')

width_value = my_window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = my_window.winfo_screenheight()
my_window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value,height_value))
my_window.configure(bg = 'white')



x0 = width_value/2
y0 = height_value/2
canvas = Canvas(my_window,height='8.7c',width='8.7c',bg='red')
canvas.create_text(100,100,fill="black",text="E")

canvas.pack()
canvas.place(x=x0,y=y0,anchor = "center")

my_window.mainloop()
```

I dont know how to proceed, either i am sure whether creating a canvas is the correct way to go about it.

I was able to solve it using turtle interface, however when i go smaller on the width, lets say for 0.725cms, the letters get very illegible. Can someone help me design this in a way it works on any scale?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some reading about fonts and how they work.  You are probably better of using vector graphics

Comment: can you help me with some direction on where i can start reading about graphics?

Comment: You can check out the turtle module built into python.

Comment: Note that you can use negative value for the font size which means in pixels.  So `canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill="black", text="E", font=("Arial", -canvas.winfo_reqheight()), anchor="nw")` may draw a letter E around the height of the canvas.

Comment: this works,  but does not give the precision am looking for!

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for giving me the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using Turtle like suggested. Here is the solution:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

def draw_e(turtle):
    t.penup()
    t.setposition(-((canvas.winfo_width()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10)),(canvas.winfo_height()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10))
    t.pendown()


    t.pensize(canvas.winfo_width()/5)
    t.pencolor("black")

    t.forward(canvas.winfo_width())
    t.backward(canvas.winfo_width())

    t.right(90)
    t.forward((canvas.winfo_width()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10))

    t.left(90)
    t.forward(canvas.winfo_width())
    t.backward(canvas.winfo_width())
    t.right(90)

    t.forward((canvas.winfo_width()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10))
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(canvas.winfo_width())

    return

def draw_f(turtle):
    t.penup()
    t.setposition(-((canvas.winfo_width()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10)),(canvas.winfo_height()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10))
    t.pendown()


    t.pensize(canvas.winfo_width()/5)
    t.pencolor("black")

    t.forward(canvas.winfo_width())
    t.backward(canvas.winfo_width())

    t.right(90)
    t.forward((canvas.winfo_width()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10))

    t.left(90)
    t.forward(canvas.winfo_width()/1.5)
    t.backward(canvas.winfo_width()/1.5)
    t.right(90)

    t.forward((canvas.winfo_width()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/10))
    

my_window = Tk()

my_window.title('VA chart')

width_value = my_window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = my_window.winfo_screenheight()
my_window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value,height_value))
my_window.configure(bg = 'white')



x0 = width_value/2
y0 = height_value/2
canvas = Canvas(my_window,height='8.7c',width='8.7c',bg='white')


canvas.pack()
canvas.place(x=x0,y=y0,anchor = "center")

print(canvas.winfo_rootx(),canvas.winfo_rooty())

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.speed('fastest') 

draw_e(t)

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `Canvas.create_line()` is more simplier.